# Entry Form doesn't save the entry and goes to 404 page

Tags: form, entry-form

I have a frontend Entry Form that will not save an entry and goes to a 404 page.

Basically i have this:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="add-a-resource__form">
{{ getCsrfInput() }}
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="entries/saveEntry">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/resources/thank-you">
<input type="hidden" name="sectionId" value="4">
<input type="hidden" name="enabled" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="typeId" value="4">
<input type="hidden" name="fields[topContent]" value="test">
</form>
```

And in the log in the session array i have:

```
'9df612913c35fa7bdbde58405537f412__timeout' => 1479139200,
  '9df612913c35fa7bdbde58405537f412Yii.CWebUser.flash.error' => 'Couldn’t save entry.',
  '9df612913c35fa7bdbde58405537f412Yii.CWebUser.flashcounters' => 
  array (
    'error' => 0,
  ),
```

I am logged in as an admin so have permission to write to the channel, the details are right in the hidden fields, but when i submit the form, it goes to a 404 page no matter what i put in the redirect input.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Right, the issues was that there was a validation error on a field, but the form didn't reload and display those errors, it just went to a 404 page.